# How to draw dash instead of null in QSpinBox?

Tags: qt, paint, keypress, qspinbox

I need to draw dash instead of null in `QSpinBox`. Also I need to make dash key pressing equalling null key pressing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setSpecialValueText()`;

```
 QSpinBox spinBox;
 spinBox->setSpecialValueText(tr("-"));
```

You can then check if the special value is selected by connecting `valueChanged(QString)` function. Note that this is different from `valueChanged(int)` You can then check the value of the passed string in a slot, and if it is equal to special text, you can do something.

```
 main()
 {
      connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(doSomething(QString)));
 }

 void doSomething(QString valueStr)
 {
     if(valueStr == spinBox->specialValueText())
           // Do something
     else
           //Convert valueStr to int and do other stuff
 }
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
 main()
 {
      connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
 }

 void doSomething()
 {
     if(spinBox->value() == 0)
           // Do something with dash
     else
           //Do something with the value
 }
```

For your other question, you need to create a keyPressEvent and check if pressed key is dash or not. If it's dash you can call another function to do something. Edit: BTW, the index of `specialValueText()` is 0.

**Edit**: Or you can create a `QShortcut` in your main function.

```
 new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Minus), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
```

**Edit continued**: doSomething() is a slot function. Put, for example `void doSomething();` in the `private slots:` section of your header file. And in the cpp file define a function similar to this:

```
 void MainWindow::doSomething()
 {
     ui->spinBox->setValue(0);
     //This is the slot called when you press dash.
 }
```

**Edit still continued**:
You need to declare a `protected:` function in the header like this:

```
 virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
```

Then you need to define this function in your cpp file. Like this:

```
 void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
 {
     if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Minus)
         ui->spinBox->setValue(0);
 }
```

You don't have to connect any signals or slots for this function. It's an event.

That means when dash is pressed `ui->spinBox->setValue(0);`

Because of that, you need to create a spinBox with a range starting from 0.

```
 spinBox->setRange(0, 100);
```

That means,

```
 if(spinBox->value() == 0)
      //Then specialValueText is selected.
```

Comment: Thanks! `specialValueText` is exactly what I need. Now `QSpinBox` also accepts dash entered by keyboard! But when focus leaved (or also when something else is happening which must fix new value) value restores. Maybe there is better way to accept dash then use `keyPressEvent`?

Comment: Are you using setValue()?

Comment: I mean you need to setValue(0); when dash is pressed.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. Currently `setValue` is not using by that `QSpinBox`.

Comment: I mean the spinbox accepts dash, because it's one of the values. But if you want the changed value to not restore, you need to define a slot function that sets the value of spinbox to 0 when dash is pressed in your application. Or you might create a QShortcut of course. Edit: instead of keyPressEvent. Edit: At least this is what I think is the problem.

Comment: I can try to give an example for that. I mean if you need that.

Comment: How can I handle this event? This is what I did but this does not work. `private slots: void onKeyPress(QKeyEvent *event);` `connect(ui->spinBox, SIGNAL(keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *)), this, SLOT(onKeyPress(QKeyEvent *)));`

Comment: See my edit please. You can also create a QShortcut more easily. You need to connect it in your main function of your mainwindow class. Edit: To be more specific put that line into your mainwindow class' main function.

Comment: See **Edit continued** in my answer.

Comment: I edited once more. I forgot to put parentheses around tr() function.

Comment: `doSomething()` is not calling. I added `new QShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("-")), this, SLOT(doSomething()));` to window contructor, declared `void doSomething();` in `private slots` of window.

Comment: It may be about dash not being a key sequence. I don't know. You might try the other solution I will edit into answer. See **Edit still continued**

Comment: Should I add a derived class for spinBox?

Comment: No you don't need that. And I'm sorry I forgot that dash is actually `Qt::Key_Minus` I updated the codes. Should work now.

Comment: That's right. We created the shortcut for MainWindow. Hmm. You can always make `ui->spinBox->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);` The spinbox would be not focusable. So if you need up and down keys for it, you can create shortcuts for them the same way.

Comment: I don't understand you. I thought that `new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Minus), this, SLOT(doSomething()));` is another solution.

Comment: You can use either keyPressEvent or QShortcut.